# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.QueryLanguage'

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, console-application

These are the references I added

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Common;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client;
```

I was getting a Microsoft.WITDataSTore64.dll error before but I fixed it by copying that to the project bin. I don't know where the WorkItemTrackimg.Client.QueryLanguage might be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to find the dll you need for team foundation server for visual studio 2015 in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer